# Updating the iterator in for loop - Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I stumbled upon this conundrum and would like to know how Python is working that causes these different outputs from the 2 sets of code. Here are the 2 for loop codes:

1. First case

   ```
    l = [1,2,3]
    for i in l:
      print(i)
      l = 0
   ```
2. Second case

   ```
    l = [1,2,3]
    for i in l:
      print(i)
      l.append(3)
   ```

For the first scenario, the output is 1, 2, 3, even though I was expecting that it should return an error since l would be updated to 0. So I tried to see what the output might be if I were to append an item to l, and it does work as I expected, which is that l does get updated, and prints out 1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,.... infinitely.

Could someone explain why just reassigning l to something doesn't get reflected in the for loop but appending an item to l does get reflected in the for loop?

Thank you!

Comment: In the first example you are reassigning the variable name `l` while in the second you mutate the object (`list`) `l` is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between re-binding a variable name and mutating the underlying object.

Case 1: You rebind the name `l` to a new value, but that doesn't change the list object, which is currently iterated through.

Case 2: You actually mutate the same list object.

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning the value `l=0` inside the loop, you are actually creating a new variable `l` that is local inside the loop, you can verify this by printing the `id` of the variable inside the loop which represents the memory address for the variable reference:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in l:
    print(id(l))
    print(i)
    l = 0
    print(id(l))
1927830512328   ->id before assigning l=0
1
140728450314480 ->id after assigning l=0
140728450314480
2
140728450314480
140728450314480
3
140728450314480
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "local inside the loop" in Python. Loops don't create scopes. The new `l` has the same scope as the list, they are local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you print the address value. 
You can check the address values from l to `id(l)`.

In the first case, if you run l = 0 in the for statement and output id(l), a value that differs from the initial address value is displayed. This indicates that the existing l and l in the for statement are different variables.

In the second case, the address value does not change. This is because the original address was accessed through a function called `append` and added a value.